# How to send multiple variable to a view in laravel when one or more variables are null

Tags: php, laravel, view, controller, eloquent

When a new user is registered and is redirected to profile page. All these `$userconatact` , `$qualification` and `$profileimage` variables are null. Home page is setup with `if (condition)` to have  buttons to fill form or show available data to user. There are three forms and user has to fill these form one by one. All these variables or one of them could be null but I still want to send the null value to view. Is there any way to make this view happen.

```
    class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    public function showprofile($type=null, $id='id'){
      $contactquery = Usercontact::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->select('*')->get();
      $usercontact = $contactquery->toArray();
      $qualificationquery = userqualification::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->select('*')->get();
      $qualification = $qualificationquery->toArray();
      $profileimagequery = Profileimage::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->select('id','user_id','profileimage')->get();
      $profileimage = $profileimagequery->toArray();

      return view('home')->withUsercontact($usercontact)->withQualification($qualification)->withProfileimage($profileimage);


    }
}
```

I tried using if statements but if didn't work

```
return view('home')
if(!empty($usercontact)){->withUsercontact($usercontact)}
if(!empty($qualification)){->withQualification($qualification)}
if(!empty($profileimage)){->withProfileimage($profileimage);}
```

Is there any way to use `if statements` like this to make it easy.

Answer (score 0):

1) Use compact which will automatically create key value pairs for you.

```
return view('home')->compact('usercontact','qualification','profileImage')
```

2) Here are a few other improvements to your code. You can use the Auth facade to access the logged-in user.

```
$usercontact = Auth::user();
```

3) Define [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships) on your user model and access the qualifications by this. This will return a Collection.

```
$qualification = $usercontact->qualifications;
```

Comment: my variables contain array and that compact return null values which is not useful

Answer (score 0):

You can use `compact` to send data from your controllers to views.

`return view('home')->compact('usercontact', 'qualification', profileimage');`

Your code can be refactored as below.

```
 public function showprofile($type=null, $id='id')
        {
          $usercontact = Usercontact::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->first();
          $qualification = Userqualification::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->first();
          $profileimage = Profileimage::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->select('id','user_id','profileimage')->first();

         return view('home')->compact('usercontact', 'qualification', 'profileimage'); 
        }
```

Note the Userqualification model name in the code according to the convention. Try to add relationships to your models to make your query easier.

Answer (score 0):

Try this style to send data to view

```
return view('home',['Usercontact'=>$usercontact,'Qualification'=>$qualification,'Profileimage'=>$profileimage]);
```

In view you will be able to get data by array key